# how can i find min of max multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, matlab, maxima-minima

I want to find: $min[y] max[x] f(x,y)$.(notation means that maximum of f on x and minimum on y).
where is: $f(x,y) = h(x)+y*x$. i want to determine y such that decrease the maximum of $f(x,y)$. $h(x)$ is nonlinear. please help me with a matlab code or analytical approach.

Comment: Are there any constraints?  If not, then $f_y(x,y)=x$, so $x=0$ at a local extrema and since $f_x(x,y)=h'(x)+y$, it must be that $y=-h'(0)$.  I don't think that this is what you're asking for, so perhaps more details would be helpful.

Comment: there is no constraint, your approach for when we want max[y] max[x] f(x,y), but h(x) has a maximum in [x_min, x_max] and the goal is find y such that decrease the maximum of f.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the points where $f$ is a maximum with respect to $x$ and a minimum with respect to $y,$ we call that point a saddle.

If $f$ is continuous and twice differential.

Find $f_x, f_y, f_{xx}, f_{yy}$ and $f_{x,y}$

Those are the partial derivatives with respect to x,y, and the second partial derivatives.

At a saddle:
$f_x = 0,  f_y = 0$ and $4f_{xx}f_{yy} < (f_{xy})^2$

Comment: suppose that h(x)=sin(x) with fx=0,fy=0 so we have y=-1, then f = sin(x)-x has a maximum greater than when we choose y=0!

Comment: if $f(x) = \sin x + xy, f_x = \cos x + y, f_y = x$ There is no point where $f_x,f_y = 0,0$ and no saddle points for this function.

Comment: (x,y)=(0,-1) implies fx=0 and fy=0; isn`t true?